# Open Google Maps InfoWindow on link click outside of map

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

This is javascript I use to make all markers and set click listener

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var markernovi, i;

    for (i = 0; i < lokacije.length; i++) {
        var ll = lokacije[i][2];
        var latlng = ll.split(',');
        markernovi = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(latlng[0]), parseFloat(latlng[1])),
            map: mapObject,
            icon: 'img/pins/' + key + '.png',
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(markernovi, 'click', (function (markernovi, i) {
            return function () {
                infowindow.setContent(lokacije[i][0]);
                infowindow.open(mapObject, markernovi);
            }
        })(markernovi, i));



    markers.push(markernovi);
    }
}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load' , initialize);

function myClick(id){
    google.maps.event.trigger(markers[id], 'click');
}
```

And I have this to list all locations on page :

```
<?php
                foreach($lokacijebuy1 as $sve) {
                    ?>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="img_wrapper">
                            <div class="img_container">
                                <a href="#" onclick="myClick(0);" >
                                    <img src="http://evidentiraj.me/gkcard/slikemjesta/<?php echo $sve['photo']; ?>" width="800" height="533" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                                    <div class="short_info">
                                        <h3><?php echo $sve['ime2']; ?></h3>
                                        <em><?php echo $sve['adresa']; ?></em>
                                        <p>
                                            <?php echo $sve['opis2']; ?>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- End img_wrapper -->
                    </div><!-- End col-md-6 -->
                <?php }
            ?>
```

And no matter which one I click only infowindow I open is the first one in array.

You can see page live here : http://evidentiraj.me/gorskikotarcard/locationsbuy.php

And I found that the only thing I need to change to display other marker is number inside myClick

```
<a href="#" onclick="myClick(1);" >
```

ANSWER:
only thing I did was to add counter in my `<a href` tag
Now it looks like this:

```
<?php
            $counter = 0;
                foreach($lokacijebuy1 as $sve) {

                    ?>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="img_wrapper">
                            <div class="img_container">
                                <a href="#" onclick="myClick(<?php echo $counter; ?>);" >
                                    <img src="http://evidentiraj.me/gkcard/slikemjesta/<?php echo $sve['photo']; ?>" width="800" height="533" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                                    <div class="short_info">
                                        <h3><?php echo $sve['ime2']; ?></h3>
                                        <em><?php echo $sve['adresa']; ?></em>
                                        <p>
                                            <?php echo $sve['opis2']; ?>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- End img_wrapper -->
                    </div><!-- End col-md-6 -->
                <?php
                    $counter++;
                }
            ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you render the `a` element with function `myClick` with input argument set to `0`, and you use this argument as an index in the markers array inside your function, which is still the first marker in the array. You need to change the way you render the `a` element to get results like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="myClick(0);"></a>
<a href="#" onclick="myClick(1);"></a>
<a href="#" onclick="myClick(2);"></a>
```

Comment: I know but i have foreach loop in which I cant do something like ID from database -1 because user can disable some locations in backend and it wouldn't work.

Comment: Can you in your ``foreach`` loop in your ``php`` code set an counter, and use that counter while rendering the ``a`` element?